# Error when trying to use or in if else statement

Tags: sml

I am trying to write a function cardcolor with or inside an if else statement using sml as shown below

```
datatype suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades;
datatype rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num of int;
type card = suit * rank;
datatype color = Red | Black;

fun cardColor(x:suit,y:rank):color = if (x = Clubs) or (x = Spades) then Black else Red;
```

but this error message is shown:

```
 assig4.m:7.53-7.55 Error: unbound variable or constructor: or
 assig4.m:7.57 Error: unbound variable or constructor: X
 assig4.m:7.38-7.88 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch] 
   operator: bool   
   in expression:   
     (x = Clubs) <errorvar>
```

How can I correct evaluate 2 statement in a if statement? I have tried using bar  X= Spades or Clubs, and different way to write it, but they all do not work with different errors showing up.

Comment: Why is `matlab` tagged here?

Answer (score 3):

The keywords for shortcutting conjunction and disjunction are `andalso` and `orelse` in SML.

```
fun cardColor(x : suit, y : rank) : color =
  if x = Clubs orelse x = Spades then Black else Red
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides Andreas Rossberg's excellent answer, you may consider using pattern matching:

```
fun cardColor suit = case suit of
         Clubs    => Black
       | Spades   => Black
       | Diamonds => Red
       | Hearts   => Red
```